# Monitor data traffic in chrome:// protocols

Tags: chrome, burp-suite, sniffing

With Burp Suite we can capture the traffic of protocols like http, https. But i want now monitor the data traffic in urls like chrome://settings

Comment: There is no traffic to monitor

Answer (score 4):

`chrome://` is not a protocol like HTTP or HTTPS. It's a scheme handled internally by chrome to display internal pages, such as your settings or your installed extensions.

Chrome does not fetch what the settings look like from some external source. It's built into the application. This is easily verifiable by opening `chrome://settings` on a machine with no network access.

If these internal sites require external data, regular HTTP or HTTPS requests are sent.

Comment: Yes i know. But these are HTML form, so the datas are being submitted. So i should actually catch them ?

Comment: @CenkTen Yes, they are HTML forms, and they are submitted. But the target is not a remote web server, it's your local chrome instance. **HTML does not necessitate HTTP.** The way you intercept them is to debug chrome.